# Can't connect to MySQL for single dyno on restart occasionally

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services

Every once in a while, when we either restart the app or a dyno gets cycled/restarted automatically, a dyno restarts but comes back up with `Can't connect to MySQL server on (url) (110)` error. In then will continuously throw `!! Unexpected error while processing request: can't modify frozen array` errors at every request we get until we manually restart the dyno. It is then perfectly fine just like all of our other dynos

```
Jan 29 22:18:23 myapp heroku/web.26:  State changed from up to starting
Jan 29 22:18:27 myapp heroku/web.26:  Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
Jan 29 22:18:29 myapp heroku/web.26:  Process exited with status 0
Jan 29 22:18:32 myapp heroku/web.26:  Starting process with command `bundle exec thin -p 41924 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
Jan 29 22:18:40 myapp app/web.26:  >> Thin web server (v1.4.1 codename Chromeo)
Jan 29 22:18:40 myapp app/web.26:  >> Maximum connections set to 1024
Jan 29 22:18:40 myapp app/web.26:  >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:41924, CTRL+C to stop
Jan 29 22:18:42 myapp heroku/web.26:  State changed from starting to up
Jan 29 22:19:08 myapp app/web.26:  Starting the New Relic Agent.
Jan 29 22:19:08 myapp app/web.26:  Installed New Relic Browser Monitoring middleware
Jan 29 22:19:08 myapp app/web.26:  ** [NewRelic][01/29/13 19:19:08 -0800 dd1c41a1-e62a-46f0-bdc8-f48919d4db3c (2)] INFO : Dispatcher: thin
Jan 29 22:19:08 myapp app/web.26:  ** [NewRelic][01/29/13 19:19:08 -0800 dd1c41a1-e62a-46f0-bdc8-f48919d4db3c (2)] INFO : Application: myapp
Jan 29 22:19:08 myapp app/web.26:  ** [NewRelic][01/29/13 19:19:08 -0800 dd1c41a1-e62a-46f0-bdc8-f48919d4db3c (2)] INFO : New Relic Ruby Agent 3.5.3 Initialized: pid = 2
Jan 29 22:19:08 myapp app/web.26:  ** [NewRelic][01/29/13 19:19:08 -0800 dd1c41a1-e62a-46f0-bdc8-f48919d4db3c (2)] INFO : NewRelic::Agent::Samplers::DelayedJobSampler sampler not available: No DJ worker present
Jan 29 22:19:18 myapp app/web.26:  ** [NewRelic][01/29/13 19:19:18 -0800 dd1c41a1-e62a-46f0-bdc8-f48919d4db3c (2)] INFO : Connected to NewRelic Service at collector-1.newrelic.com
Jan 29 22:19:18 myapp app/web.26:  ** [NewRelic][01/29/13 19:19:18 -0800 dd1c41a1-e62a-46f0-bdc8-f48919d4db3c (2)] INFO : Reporting performance data every 60 seconds.
Jan 29 22:19:31 myapp app/web.26:  !! Unexpected error while processing request: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'myrdsinstance.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)
Jan 29 22:19:31 myapp app/web.26:  !! Unexpected error while processing request: can't modify frozen array
Jan 29 22:19:31 myapp app/web.26:  !! Unexpected error while processing request: can't modify frozen array
Jan 29 22:19:31 myapp app/web.26:  !! Unexpected error while processing request: can't modify frozen array
Jan 29 22:19:31 myapp app/web.26:  !! Unexpected error while processing request: can't modify frozen array
Jan 29 22:19:31 myapp app/web.26:  !! Unexpected error while processing request: can't modify frozen array
```

Our MySQL instance is an RDS instance and we have never encountered issues connecting to it from other EC2 instances or locally, only from our Heroku dynos.

Thinking that it might be [`back_log`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_back_log) issue, we upped that value, but it had no effect on the occurance of the errors.

What else can we try to help either diagnose what is going wrong or to eliminate this connection issue? Being on RDS and Heroku, our logging options seem rather limited... Is there some way of making MySQL automatically reconnect its connection, since Heroku overrites your database.yml?

Comment: Just letting you know that we see this too. We set a variable on our connection (read timeout) which causes us to load ActiveRecord during initialization. When we get a cannot connect, it causes the launch to fail and the dyno/worker just gets recycled.